# What's the right way to switch database using sqlsrv?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm starting to work with PHP 7 with mssql right now, and I was needing to switch the sql functions from mssql_ to sqlsrv_. When I was using mssql functions, I was changing the database with the function mssql_change_db, but as I saw now, there are no alternatives functions to use instead of this function. I thought to make this function buy myself, by using USE[DB] in every query but it seems to be useless or r ineffective. I've thought about another way, which seems to be better. 
The another way that I've think about it's to add before every table name the DB_NAME.dbo.table. 
I have also started to build a function to that way, which finds the table name and adding automaticly the database name with the ".dbo" before the table name. 
Here is what I did until now: ( I just started to build it ) 
It's just an example, of curse it's not finished yet.

```
public function exec($mainQuery, $db = NULL)
{
    if(isset($db)) {
        $query = $mainQuery;
        $query = explode('from ', $query); 
        $query = $query[1]; // Getting the rest of the query after the word "Form"
        if (strpos($query, 'where') !== false) { // Checking if the rest of the query includes the word "Where"
            $query = explode('where', $query); // Taking the word before the word "Where"
            $tableName = $query[0];
        }
        else { // The rest of the query is actually the table name, because there is no "Where" in the query
            $tableName = $query;
        }

        $pQuery = str_replace( "$tableName", " $db.dbo.$tableName", $mainQuery); // Replacing the table name with the DB.dbo.tablename

        return sqlsrv_query($this -> sqlHandle, $pQuery);
    }
    else {
        return sqlsrv_query($this -> sqlHandle, $mainQuery);
    }
}
```

I should build it also for JOIN, INSERT (INTO), UPDATE. 
I don't know why, but I feel like it's bad way to do that, 
that's why I ask you what's the better way to switch databases. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a not good idea to use `USE Database` or some how change database in query, running from PHP (you did a really nice trick with DB names). For that kind of stuff better use stored procedures and call them from PHP.

In that case you don't need to think about in what schema or database your table is, that all is written in SP.

One more way is to use one default database for all users, and use `USE database` when you need to get table from not-default DB.

Comment: Thanks for answering me, the point is that there is no "default database" in my case, I'm using 6 databases, and I use all of them at every code page I'm coding, I didn't make the databases by myself, it's something that inserts to it data. thank you, I think I'll go on my way.